# Opposite of INT into STRING

Tags: java, android

What is the Opposite of this code in to string?

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
```

Comment: `input.setText(Integer.toString(number))`. Which you'd have known very quickly if you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and [`TextComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/TextComponent.html)(?).

Answer (score 7):

The opposite of `String` to an `int` would be an `int` to a `String`.

```
String strNumber = String.valueOf(number); //< fast and efficient.
```

or

```
String strNumber = "" + number; //< lazy and slow.
```

Comment: Opposite of [`int Integer.parseInt(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) is [`String Integer.toString(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-). Both of them has an overload that takes an `int radix` (which `String.valueOf` doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods to convert integer to string. Few of them are listed below.

Method 1

```
String.valueOf(int_value);
```

Method 2

```
Integer.toString(int_value);
```

Method 3

```
int_value.toString;
```

Comment: `int_value.toString;` is not legal Java.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
 int a=5;
 String s = ""+a;
```

or

```
int a =5;
String s=Integer.toString(a);
```